# MWSimpleAdminCrudBundle - export filter results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using MWSimpleAdminCrudBundle on my Symfony project, which is delivered from SensioGeneratorBundle. The bundle offers filter over entities and also export of the entities (PDF, XLS, JSON). What I would expect is that when I have active filter, also the filter results are exported.. But I always get all entities, nevermind filter results. Please see https://github.com/MWSimple/AdminCrudBundle/blob/version30/Controller/DefaultController.php#L89 , if someone could figure out how to pass the filter results to query (they are also stored in session), I would be very happy! I have spent one hour now debugging and testing but I cannot find out how to do it... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To pass the filter to the query, they use:

```
$this->get('lexik_form_filter.query_builder_updater')->addFilterConditions($filterForm, $queryBuilder);
```

In their filter method code:

```
// Get filter from session
if ($this->configArray['sessionFilter'] && $session->has($this->configArray['sessionFilter'])) {
    $filterData = $session->get($this->configArray['sessionFilter']);
    $filterForm->submit($filterData);
    $this->get('lexik_form_filter.query_builder_updater')->addFilterConditions($filterForm, $this->queryBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that it is applicable to FormInterface only.. But not query in common :/